# Prove by using the inverse functions, $f$ is surjective if and only if $h \circ f \circ g$ is surjective

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

Let $f: A \to B$ be a function and $g: A \to A$, $h: B \to B$ be bijections. Prove by using the inverse functions, $f$ is surjective if and only if $h \circ f \circ g$ is surjective.

I can see a very clear proof for the first direction, however it doesn't use the inverse functions. Maybe it is acceptable to use the inverse functions on only the second direction.

$\Rightarrow$: Suppose $f$ is surjective

Since $g$ is bijective, then $f \circ g$ is surjective

Similarly, since h is a bijection, then $h \circ (f \circ g)$ is surjective

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose $h \circ f \circ g$ is surjective.

Comment: Please use $\rm\LaTeX$ for math objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $h^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ are bijective and thus surjective we have $$(h \circ f \circ g)\circ g^{-1}= h \circ f$$ is surjective and so $$h^{-1} \circ (h \circ f) = f$$ is surjective.